# Changes to talk/ytalk or alternative chat in the Linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, debian-squeeze, chat

While looking for a piece of software that provides chat between 2 Linux server users logged in the terminal, I tried **talk/ytalk**. Unfortuntaley it provides chat between  users on separate walls (each user has its own wall) and the messages lack timestamps. **Is it possible to set it up so that at least timestamps are provided**?

Alternatively, **is there any other software that could provide one wall on which users write messages prepended with time?** Simple chat with messages listed in the order of submission would be ideal:

```
13:05:48 [bridgekeeper@...]: What is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?
13:06:28 [cascaval@...]: What do you mean? An African or European swallow?
```

I already tried **wall** and **write** but they don't fit the bill.

OS: Debian 6.0

Comment: Have you tried 'write' ?

Comment: I noticed **write** in my search but haven't tried it. Now I gave it a shot and it seems to be similar to **wall** though the messages go to only one user. Still it's not really a chat wall with timestamped messages.

Comment: Now when I think of it, I could get by with the split window of **ytalk** if each message had the timestamp prefixed.

Comment: I tweaked the question as some people seem to be unhappy about it.

Comment: I suspect the answer is going to come down to "No".

Comment: @PJC: Yes, I'm afraid I'll have to consider some more complicated options as already before I posted the question the Google results didn't bring anything that would match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may accuse me of overkill, but I think an XMPP (Jabber) server would fit the bill.  [ejabberd](http://ejabberd.im) is a world-class Jabber server that's very easy to set up on Linux.

Once you have a Jabber server, you can create two or more accounts, then use any instant messaging program to chat.  For the Linux console, I recommend [mcabber](http://mcabber.com/).  I personally use it.  It has timestamps, logging, presence notifications, and you can even set up ad-hoc chat rooms for three or more people.

Comment: Yes, a bit more complicated in my opinion in the same way as in ekaj's answer but it would certainly be an option to consider so thank you and +1 for your input. Another option that I already know about is the use of **finch** + **avahi**.

Answer (score 2):

Look up [irssi](http://irssi.org/). You can customize it to your needs.

Comment: That would require IRC server to be set up on the machine, right?

Comment: I see. I was hoping for some simpler solution but if not found, I'll consider something more complicated and this would surely be one of the options so thanks and +1 for the answer.

Comment: It's easy to use but I would have to set up an IRC server as I don't want the communication to go through a 3rd party server.

Comment: Yes, with some GPG based plugin I could get the security. The thing is, why to run it through the 3rd party server at all (well apart from not having to install/setup local IRC server)? It looks like an extra link in the chain that might thus bring extra issues.

Comment: But that's the thing. Why to run the communication between 2 local users through a 3rd party server and thus have the security concern?

Comment: If your hiding something THAT secretive, people will just hack into your server... I doubt anything you're doing is that sensitive if you're discussing how to do it on an internet help site